# How do you resolve circular dependencies in Angular

Tags: angularjs, circular-dependency, angular-services

I have a `NewsService` and `PersonService` and a model for `Person` and for `NewsItem`. The following is a simplified representation excluding services.

```
//angular service to expose Person
var Person = function(data) {
    angular.copy(data, this);
    //some other initialisation
}
Person.prototype.getNews = function() {
    //fetch news
    .then(function(newsItems) {
        return newsItems.map(function(newsItemData){
            newsItemData.author = new Person(newsItemData.author);
            return new NewsItem(newsItemData);
        });
    });
}

//Angular service to expose NewsItem
var NewsItem = function(data) {
    angular.copy(data, this);
    //some other initialisation
}
NewsItem.prototype.getComments = function() {
    //fetch comments
    .then(function(commentsData){
        return comments.map(function(commentData) {
            commentData.author = new Person(commentData.author);
            return new Comment(commentData);
        });
    });
}

//Angular services that reference these objects
NewsService
PersonService
```

NewsItem and Person reference each other because the data fetched from their respective APIs includes data that should be instantiated by the other object. There are numerous pairs of services and models referencing each other and I have a problem with circular dependencies forcing me to instantiate objects elsewhere, which I want to avoid. I can't think of an elegant solution and could really use your help.

Comment: Use 3 objects:  One for `NewsItems`, one for `Persons`, and one to associate the two (call it `Items` or whatever you want).